# Resume time memory optimization

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-memory

I am writing this question based on some facts.
Such as we can not control Garbage Collector(GC) explicitly.So there is also no way to check when GC will fetch memory from my paused activity.

Test Case i am talking about:
I have allocated many objects including HashMaps and ArrayLists in my onCreate method.
Some of them are used to store references of bitmaps.
Now user is pausing the activity by pressing home button.
Than i forget to resume the same one after performing other tasks for a long time.
And now when i come back to my paused activity.

Problem is :1) Is there any chance to pretend or assume like what memeory GC will fetch first in this case?

2) Does gc fetch whole activity or few of the idle and null objects only ?

3) Suppose after a long time say around 5 to 6 hours user is resuming the activity how can i know that some of the objects are garbage collected .

4) If some of the objects are garbage collected than checking them to null in onResume is sufficient way to access them further or not .

5) How to handle Null Pointer Access in such kind of situation.

I would love to hear every suggestion.
Thank you for looking.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know GC runs over all objects that are in VM, and if there is no reference to an object, it is removed. It's a bit different about Android Activity which has it's own [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). 

When Androids needs more RAM for other apps (activities) then in your Activity  `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` is called. In this place you should save everything you need to `Bundle` When the user comes back to your Activity you can restore those object in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

EDIT: Piece of my app as an example:

```java
public class Window {
    public Window(Bundle bundle) {
        maximized = bundle.getBoolean("maximized", maximized);
        displayed = bundle.getBoolean("displayed", displayed);
        minimized = bundle.getBoolean("minimized", minimized);
        resizable = bundle.getBoolean("resizable", resizable);
        orientation = bundle.getInt("orientation");
    }
    public Bundle bundle() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("maximized", maximized);
        bundle.putBoolean("displayed", displayed);
        bundle.putBoolean("minimized", minimized);
        bundle.putBoolean("resizable", resizable);
        bundle.putInt("orientation", orientation);
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

And MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Window> windows;
    [...]

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle[] windowsBundle = new Bundle[windows.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<windowsBundle.length; i++){
            windowsBundle[i] = windows.get(i).bundle();
        }
        savedInstanceState.putParcelableArray("windows", windowsBundle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Parcelable[] windowsParcels = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("windows");
        Bundle[] windowsBundle = (Bundle[]) Arrays.copyOf(windowsParcels, windowsParcels.length, Bundle[].class);
        windowsParcels = null;
        for(int i=0; i<windowsBundle.length; i++){
            windows.add(new Window(windowsBundle[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean i should do it on each activity even if i navigate inside my application.

Comment: Yes. Saving every object to bundle may seem to be tiring, but it's been discused that it is the best way of preserving your activity data.

Answer (score 1):

If your activity has been in the background for 5 or 6 hours, it is almost guaranteed that Android has killed the hosting process. When the user returns to your app, Android will create a new process for the app and then reinstantiate one single activity. In general, after 5 or 6 hours, Android will have discarded any saved state and just restart your app from the beginning (unless you've specifically specified `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` for your root activity (the start activity).

If you return to your 'paused' activity after 5 or 6 hours, and the app's process has been killed and recreated, `onCreate()` will again be called on your activity before `onResume()`.

GC has nothing to do with this. If your activity instance is alive, GC will not reclaim any objects referenced by it. If you are seeing variables being set to `null`, this is because Android has killed your process and then later created a new one.

Comment: Well AFAIK android only kills your activity or (application) in the case of memory shortage and based on frequent usage,I really doubt if it kills any paused activity just based on time.I am really interested in your answer because if it kills a process its necessary to release all the memory references allocated by it.And here comes GC in picture.

Comment: Actually, Android can kill your process at any time (if it is in the background). On newer devices (Android 4.0 and up), especially on HTC devices, "process killing" is much more aggressive. In most cases, if your app is in the background more than a few minutes it is likely to be killed. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) for an explanation of Android clearing a task when it has been paused for 30 minutes.

Comment: Regarding your comment about GC and process killing, you've got this wrong: When Android kills your process, it just kills the OS process. Boom. Gone. It doesn't call `onDestroy()` on any components, it doesn't call the GC at all, because when it kills the process the VM (Virtual Machine) is also killed, so it doesn't need to cleanup any resources. Android does this a lot, and you need to make sure that your code can handle it.